# Is there a naming scheme is appropriate for referring to a file within an archive?

Tags: namespaces, filesystems

I'm working on an application which is supposed to be able to refer not only to files directly, but also files located within an archive (such as ZIP or TAR). As an example, suppose I have the archive `foo.zip`, inside of which I have a directory `bar` and a file `fred.txt`. If I want to refer to the archive as a whole, I would write `foo.zip`; if I wanted to  refer to the `fred.txt` inside the archive, I would use something similar to

`foo.zip#bar/fred.txt`

where the octothorpe indicates "change of namespace" from file system to archive.

Before I go running off and reinvent the wheel, I wanted to discover whether there already is an established way to refer to a file within an archive in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a convention in Java to use a `!` for URLs of resources inside compressed files, see for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will use a variation of this unless a co-worker has a cow.